# typeahead.js shows only one option when remote server returns more

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I use the `typeahead.js` plugin to get an autocomplete list for selecting users. It's simple and it should just work, but it doesn't.

The server returns 4 objects to display in autocomplete list, but it only shows the first one. Why? I want to have all of them to give user to choose.

Please take a look at this image:

[image]

My JS code looks like:

```
     userName.typeahead({
        hint: false,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 2
    },
    {
        source: new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: '/ajax/searchUserByName?name=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY',
                cache: false
            }
        }),
        templates: {
            suggestion: function (user) {
                return '<p>' + user.name + '</p>';
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Seems you're missing the `valueKey` attribute in your `userName.typeahead({..` initialization. Add it and then try running your page.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it doesn't work. I added also `dupChecker: false` and I still see only one option.